# Visual Studio for Mac 2019 .NET Assemblies missing

Tags: macos-catalina, visual-studio-mac

I've been writing a .NET Standard 2.1 class library project in Visual Studio for Mac 2019. However, when I was trying to add an attribute to a class, I was expecting I would be able to use quick-fix to add the reference for me. So when I was trying to do just that, it does not have the option of referencing the correct using statement. So I tried to add the assembly myself but then when I tried adding a new reference, I could only see the projects in the solution, but no .NET Assemblies. See the screenshot below.

By the way, I am running:

- OSX Catalina version 10.15.3
- Visual Studio for Mac 2019 Community Edition version 8.5.4 (Build 12)

[image]

Comment: .NET Standard projects do not show assemblies in the .NET Assembly tab in the References dialog. .NET Standard projects use NuGet packages and framework targeting packs instead of the GAC so there is nothing to list in that tab.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think you should put that as the answer so I can mark it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Standard projects do not show assemblies in the .NET Assembly tab in the References dialog.

.NET Standard projects use NuGet packages and framework targeting packs instead of the GAC so there is nothing to list in that tab.